# Rewind print job under Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, printing, novell

We are in the transition from Novell NetWare to Windows server 2008. In case of the printer server we print jobs thousands of pages long.

NetWare printer manager has a handy function which allows to rewind a print job to a specified page. In case of a paper jam at the 750 page on a 800 page document this is really convenient.
Does anybody know if there is a solution for this?

The lists printed are in plain ascii lists with printer command characters embedded, and we are using dot matrix printers.

Thanks for any help or suggestion.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if what you're looking for is available natively on Windows but a solution I've implemented in a previous role to work around the same problem is to print to an electronic format, normally PDF, instead of printing directly to the printer and then printing that file. When problems occur simply reprint from the appropriate point in the file.

When using modern laser printers the problem is normally eliminated completely by using an printer which will reprint the page at which the problem occurred and continue from there on. I don't know if there are any dot matrix printers smart enough to do that, as printers were generally pretty dumb way back then. I'm assuming of course that you can't run those jobs on a laser printer for some reason.

Comment: I think you'd be surprised to learn how much legacy software/hardware is still being used out there.

Comment: @Uninspired, I'm trying very hard to work out what that comment has to do with what I posted. Did I say something that suggested I'm new to this stuff and might be unaware that there is still a fair bit of old software and hardware still in use?